# How would I be able to test the below code so that I can see how the tiebreaker would function?

Tags: python

As you can see, I'm a complete beginner at Python so any help would be appreciated. My issue is that I'm trying to test the code for all the scenarios, but I'm unable to test the tiebreaker. Sure, I could just insert `Player1Score = Player2Score` (which I've hash tagged to show the location) but that would just send the program into an endless loop, which defeats the purpose of the tiebreaker. So is there any way that I can I can have the program only go through the tiebreaker segment once and then let a single player win?

(I apologize if I've made any errors with my question, I'm new to stackoverflow as well)

```py
import random

def DiceGame():
  Count = 0
  Player1Score = 0
  Player2Score = 0
  while Count <= 4:
    Count += 1
    print ("\n It is Round",Count, "\n")
    print ("It is Player 1's turn.")
    x = input("Press [Enter] to roll.")
    Score = Rolls()
    Player1Score += Score
    print ("Player 1, your score so far is",Player1Score)
    print ("It is Player 2's turn.")
    x = input("Press [Enter] to roll.")
    Score = Rolls()
    Player2Score += Score
    print ("Player 2, your score so far is",Player2Score)
  #Player1Score = Player2Score
  if Player1Score == Player2Score:
    print ("It is a tie!")
    print ("There will be a final tiebreaker.")
    Count -= 1
    DiceGame()
  elif Player1Score >= Player2Score:
    print ("Player 1 wins!")
  elif Player1Score <= Player2Score:
    print ("Player 2 wins!")


def Rolls():
  Roll1 = random.randint(1,6)
  Roll2 = random.randint(1,6)
  print ("You got a",Roll1)
  print ("You got a",Roll2)
  Score1 = Roll1 + Roll2
  if Score1 == 2 or Score1 == 4 or Score1 == 6 or Score1 == 8 or Score1 == 10 or Score1 == 12:
    print ("Your total is even so you get an extra 10 pts.")
    Score2 = Score1 + 10
    print ("Your score for this round is" ,Score2)
  elif Score1 == 3 or Score1 == 5 or Score1 == 7 or Score1 == 9 or Score1 == 11:
    print ("Your total is odd so you lose 5 pts.")
    Score2 = Score1 - 5
    if Score2 <= 0:
      print ("Your score has gone below 0pts. It will therefore be reset to 0pts")
      Score2 = 0
    print ("Your score for this round is" ,Score2)
  
  return Score2

DiceGame()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to, you can add temporary player scores to test the function, and then remove them again if you see they work. Usually running it would just be good enough, but as you mentioned it would loop forever. This does kinda show that it works though, I guess, but I agree it's not optimal.

```
def DiceGame(count, p1, p2):
  Count = count
  Player1Score = p1
  Player2Score = p2
  ...
```

Then at the bottom of your file call it as `DiceGame(5, 1, 1)`, and in your tiebreaker call it as `DiceGame(0, 0, 0)`. This will force a tie on the first run, and will run it normally the second time.

```
if Player1Score == Player2Score:
    print ("It is a tie!")
    print ("There will be a final tiebreaker.")
    Count -= 1
    DiceGame(0, 0, 0)

... #  code inbetween

#  end of file
    return score2

DiceGame(5, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't done much on calling functions with specified variables, so I didn't think of using it to skip to Round 5.

Comment: @Shirotama No problem, but if this solved your problem you should mark it as the correct answer :)